# Nativescript:Oauth Not working

Tags: android, facebook, oauth, nativescript, npm-install

I am trying to create a Facebook Oauth System for my NativeScript Android App.I have installed nativescript-oauth from my app's folder directory like this-

```
tns plugin add nativescript-oauth
```

Inside my node_modules folder a "nativescript-oauth" folder has been created and  dependency also has been updated in composer.json.

In my App.js file,I add this-

```
    var applicationModule = require("application");
    var tnsOAuthModule = require("nativescript-oauth");
    applicationModule.start({ moduleName: "views/login/login" });
```

But I am getting this error-
 **Failed to find module:"nativescript:oauth",relative to: /app/tns_modules/**

I have also tried this-

```
import * as tnsOAuthModule from ‘nativescript-oauth’;
```

But No luck.I am getting another error.What can I do?

Comment: In case your are using NativeScript `template-hello-world-ts` template you should be able to import the module like this `import * as tnsOAuthModule from 'nativescript-oauth';` You could also try to remove `platforms` `node_modules`, `hooks` and `lib` folders and to try to rebuild your folder

Comment: Please give a full answer.Suggestion in comment is not appreciated.I don't use that template.

Comment: You could review the plugin demo project - https://github.com/alexziskind1/nativescript-oauth/tree/master/demo . In case you are using vanilla JavaScript for your app the correct way to insert module in your project is `var tnsOAuthModule = require("nativescript-oauth");`. The given information is not enough to be able to reproduce you problem. You could give sample project or to describe steps, how to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Ok Sir,I have mentioned that I tried just as like you say.But it didn't work.

Comment: If you want,I can share further steps.But I think you don't need that.

Comment: Verify whether this is not something related with your project. You could create clear project with `tns create <project_name>`. Add the plugin with `tns plugin add nativescript-oauth`. Then try to `require` the plugin with `var tnsOAuthModule = require("nativescript-oauth");` in your `app.js` file.

Comment: I have done this as like you say.And I.also search the project which you have provided.

Comment: Hi Asm, the nativescript-oauth plugin has been updated. Please get the latest from npm and see if that helps out.